# UINavigationBar without UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I want to have a `UINavigationBar` in the top of my app, just like in the phone app for example, but I don't want to use it with a `UINavigationController`, that is, I want to use it as a "standalone" object.

The view controller that will have the `UINavigationBar` has its view in a *.xib* file. I tried to drag an instance of `UINavigationBar` from the *Object Library* and it works fine, but the status bar of the app is still white while the `UINavigationBar` is gray. I want the status bar to have the same gray tone, but not the rest of the view.

To show you what I mean, I have two pictures. The first is the phone app. Notice that the status bar and the navigation bar is gray but the background is white.

[image: iPhone Phone App]

The following picture is from my app, as you can see the status bar is white (I want it to be gray as well).

[image: My iPhone app]

I have also tried to use the following code in the view controller.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Köp ProViva";
}
```

I tried it both with and without the `UINavigationBar` but either no navigation bar shows up or it looks the same as before.

**How can I add a UINavigationBar and have the status bar have the same color?**

Comment: "the status bar of the app is still white while the UINavigationBar is gray". Please explain how the `UINavigationBar` is gray. It looks white to me (with black text)

Comment: @staticVoidMan I think it looks like gray, but it is a very _light_-gray :D

Comment: hm... super light indeed. so... you want the background color of statusBar and navigationBar as lightGray?

Comment: @staticVoidMan Yes, exactly. The background color already is light gray by default, but the status bar is white. I think that the status bar will change to light gray if you manage to set the `UINavigationBar` in a special way (like the answer by Rushabh).

Comment: ok, I posted an answer. hopefully that might help

Comment: simply set imageview with 320 x 65 px in each view and set image that you want. else setting color of imageview.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can implement the delegate method `-positionForBar:` of the `UINavigationBarDelegate` protocol and simply return `UIBarPositionTopAttached`.

Example:

```
-(UIBarPosition)positionForBar:(id<UIBarPositioning>)bar
{
    return UIBarPositionTopAttached;
}
```

---

```
//if you're not using a `UINavigationController` and instead
//simply want a `UINavigationBar` then use the following method as well
-(void)testMethod
{
    UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] init];
    [navBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
    [navBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [navBar setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addSubview:navBar];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is through code. But, is it possible from the interface builder itself. As in interface builder, if  I drag and drop a UINavigationBar I can't change the height. In the Controller I do have UIBarPositionTopAttached.

Comment: Yes. Just set the controller as the delegate of your navigation bar as mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

//Creating the plain Navigation Bar

```
UINavigationBar *headerView = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
headerView.topItem.title = @"title";
[self.view addSubview:headerView];
```

Comment: How do I change the title of it?

Comment: I was able to add the `UINavigationBar` (and it looks like I want) but if I change the title (using your second code row) it does not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can't modify the status bar background color directly but since it is transparent (*since iOS7*), you can place a `UIView` of 20px in height behind the status bar with the desired color and it will appear as if the status bar has a background color.

As for the `UINavigationBar`, it's just modifying a `UINavigationBar` object that will help.

Example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //...

    //ISSUE 1: StatusBar Background
    UIView *vwStatusBarUnderlay = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [vwStatusBarUnderlay setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 20)];
    [vwStatusBarUnderlay setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:vwStatusBarUnderlay];
    //[vwStatusBarUnderlay sendSubviewToBack:self.view];

    //ISSUE 2: NavigationBar
    UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] init];
    [navBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
    [navBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [navBar setTranslucent:NO];

    UINavigationItem *navItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] init];
    [navItem setTitle:@"Favoriter"];
    [navItem setRightBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:nil action:nil]];

    [navBar setItems:@[navItem]];
    [self.view addSubview:navBar];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First answer worked well for me, but here it's in Swift instead of Objective-C:

1- you set the delegate of the navbar to the viewcontroller, whether via storyboard or the code.

2- add UINavigationBarDelegate to your controller protocols or extend it as follow:

```
extension ViewController: UINavigationBarDelegate {
    func positionForBar(bar: UIBarPositioning) -> UIBarPosition {
        return UIBarPosition.TopAttached
    }
}
```

That's it, works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

We can't set the color of the status bar by our choice, what we can do is;

In the AppDelegate.m file;

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
      //Set status bar style here
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class TopAttachedNavigationBarDelagete: NSObject, UINavigationBarDelegate {
    func position(for bar: UIBarPositioning) -> UIBarPosition {
        return .topAttached
    }
}
```

1. In Interface Builder add an Object and set it's class to `TopAttachedNavigationBarDelagete`
2. Select an UINavigationBar and in Connections Inspector connect the delegate property with previously created object