# UINavigationBar without UINavigationController from Interface Builder

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I am trying to add UINavigationBar from Interface Builder (not storyBoard).

But, the height remains as 44.

There is one post , which has a answer but thats through code.
[UINavigationBar without UINavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23107231/uinavigationbar-without-uinavigationcontroller)

I did the same but from Interface builder But did not find working. Interface builder and simulator Screen shots are attached with this email.
Also, I did add the following method in the Controller.

So, Is it possible from Interface builder?

```
- (UIBarPosition)positionForBar:(id<UIBarPositioning>)bar
{
    return UIBarPositionTopAttached;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Although it may be counter-intuitive, you need to have a constraint with the value of `20` from the top of the view (The constraint should say **Top Space to: Top Layout Guide**). In the end it should look something like this in interface builder, but during runtime, the navigation bar will add 20 points (or pixels I'm not sure) to the top, making it stretch to the top of the screen.

[image: UINavigationBar in Interface Builder]

Comment: I think its available only in storyboard.

Comment: @andyPaul If you're using a nib, just move the navigation bar 20 pixels down and if it complains, update the autolayout constraints.

Comment: Yes but those first 20 pixels it takes the orange color, actually the heigh of the navigationbar should be 64.

Comment: @andyPaul it shows the orange colour in IB but it fills it with the Nav bar when you run the app. Just give it a try.